# Python seek shift and seek end

Tags: python

Hi Guys i'm a beginner in python, 
The problem is this...

So when i open again the file, i try to add a newline at the end of file.
this is a piece of code:

```
url = "https://www.amazon.it/seven-deadly-sins-15/dp/8822602994"
command = "curl -i "+url
print command
file = subprocess.check_output(command,shell=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(file,"html.parser")
out_file = open("nomi.txt","wb+")
s = soup.find('span',id='productTitle').get_text()+","
dim = sys.getsizeof(s)
out_file.seek(0,2)
print s
print dim
out_file.write(s)
out_file.close()
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks for their help.
Have a nice Day.

Comment: You never close the file. Also, you could've opened it for _appending_ (aka `"a"` option).

Comment: So, i will inser my real code and not a example

Comment: sorry if i don't do it before

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to open the file in binary "b" or "rb" mode. You can then use seek to move to a given position. It would also be a good idea to use a context manager so you don't have to worry about closing the file when you're done. For example -

```
with open("file.txt", "rb") as f:
    f.seek(2)
    # do some other stuff with f
```

Comment: if after f.seek(2) i add f.write(s), it doesn't stay at the end of file... why ?